# I want to migrate Webforms from one environment to another, how should I got about?

Tags: webforms, migrations

We have developed a couple of webforms on a development environment, which we now want to transfer to test. How can I tackle this other than retyping the form?

Comment: Hi - i am new to StackExchange - I take it that once you mark as 'duplicate' it prevents answers? I am not disagreeing that this is a duplicate but think there might be a better thread to point to. Node Export works well now with Webform, especially Webform-CiviCRM forms (which is perhaps what ErikH is asking about since he spends so much time on civi forums ;-)

Comment: There was a discussion here http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,33653.msg142704.html#msg142704 about using Node Export and fact that with the CiviCRM tab one just needs to go in and reset eg 3 x contacts, and 2 x emails but you don't need to rebuild the form. hope that helps

Comment: Hi @petednz-drupal, when we mark something as duplicate it means a duplicate of another question asked on this site - if you've come across a better duplicate please let me know and I'll make the change...if there's a point that makes this question a bit different (e.g. integration with webform_civicrm), and might change the answers, if that information could be added to the question we'll get this opened back up so it can be answered in its own right

Comment: Interesting that my initial response to this question would have been to suggest using Node Export, which I have used myself to good effect. The answer that is referred to in the duplicate link however makes no mention of Node export, but instead refers to another module that I've never heard of before. I guess the thing to do is comment on that thread accordingly.

Comment: yep thanks for advice on SE process. Perhaps if ErikH confirms if this was a civicrm integrated webform then we should open this ticket as a separate question and add the comments you and i added to that other one back over here ;-)

Comment: It was indeed a civicrm integrated webform!